# Why is Manavala Mamunigal covered with a hood of Adi Shesha?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, adisesha, manavala-mamunigal

Sri Vaishnava acharya [Manava Mamunigal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manavala_Mamunigal) (also known as Varavara muni or Manavala Mahamunigal.) is always depicted to have covered with hoods of snake. The snake is Adi Shesha.

[image: Manavala Mamunigal]

There are many idols and utsava murtis in Divya deshams which show him covered completely with Adi Shesha.

[image: Manavala Mamunigal utsava murty at Tiruvelukka]

Above is the [Utsavar (processional deity) of Manavala Mamunigal](https://anudinam.org/2013/11/07/thiruvelukkai-swami-manavala-mamunigal-avathara-utsavam/) at Tiruvelukkai, one of Divyadeshams.

Why is Manavala Mahamunigal covered by a hood of Adi Shesha? What does this represent? Is there any story explaining his relation with Adi Shesha?

Answer (score 4):

Once, *periya perumAL* (Lord *ranganAtha* of *SrIrangam*) sought to *maNavALa mAmunigaL* to offer a discourse on *thiruvAymozhi* and *mAmunigaL* did so, using the *IDu muppaththARAyirappaDi vyAkhyAnam* of *svAmi nampiLLai* as penned down by *vaDakku thiruvIdhip piLLai*, citing many verses from the scriptures to support the *vyAkhyAnam* at the required places. This went on for about a year, till which time *namperumAL* (the processional deity of *SrIrangam* temple) ordered not to have any *utsavams* conducted. At the end of the *kAlakshEpam*, *namperumAL* appeared in the form of a young boy and offered the renowned *SrISailESa dayApAtram thaniyan* to *mAmunigaL*, along with His very own beloved *SESa paryankam* (*thiruvananthAzhvAn* as the cot, on which He reclines) as the *gurudakshiNa* to *mAmunigaL*. Hence, it is *mAmunigaL* alone who is seen with such a "serpent hood", which is in fact a "serpent cot".

Answer (score 0):

Adieyn, As far as i recollect from what i heard from Thiruchitrakutam A.V.Rangachari swamigal, he was given the serpent asana by Lord Ranganatha himself which was not even given to Udaiyavar and that is a greatness of that avatar.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).